# PHP jQuery Data-Attribute populate dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, custom-data-attribute

I have an HREF with various data-attributes (about 8) that come from a PHP query and loaded into a table.  When you click the button, it takes the data-attributes via jQuery and sends them to a modal window, where I can use them in a form.

I can open the window and place the attributes into an INPUT field with no problem.

What I would like to do is place the attribute in the first OPTION in a SELECT dropdown.

Here is the button with the attributes:

```
 <tr><td><a href='' class='modAccount' 
    data-modcode=".$row[partner_code]." 
    data-modname=\"".$row[partner_name]."\" 
    data-boiler=\"".$row[boilerplate]."\" 
    data-surcharges=\"".$row[no_new_surcharges]."\" 
    data-ccalog=\"".$row[cca_logistics]."\"  
    data-toggle='modal'>Click</a></td></tr>
```

I have quite a few data-attributes.  I had to eliminate a few for this question.

Here is the jQuery used to retrieve the data-attributes and send them to a modal window, called modifyModal.

Here is the jQuery:

```
 $(function()
 {
   $('.modAccount').click(function(e)
   {
     e.preventDefault();
     $partnerCode = $(this).attr('data-modcode');
     $partnerName = $(this).attr('data-modname');
     $boiler = $(this).attr('data-boiler');
     $surcharges = $(this).attr('data-surcharges');
     $ccalog = $(this).attr('data-ccalog');
       // the 5 below currently populate the INPUT fields for the ID's listed
     $('#modpartnerCode').val($partnerCode);  
     $('#modpartnerName').val($partnerName);
     $('#modplatform').val($platform);  // <- should go to dropdown
     $('#modboiler').val($boiler);  // <- should go to dropdown
     $('#modsurcharges').val($surcharges);  // <- should go to dropdown
   });
 });    
 $(document).on("click", ".modAccount", function () 
 {
   $('#modifyModal').modal('show');
 });
```

As you've probably read in the note above, I can send the attributes to the INPUT fields with their respective IDs.

I need to be able to populate the first OPTION of a dropdown SELECT field.

I don't think I need to show the MODAL window code.  As stated, I can populate the INPUT fields using the ID's I listed.

How can I get the IDs to populate the dropdown SELECT first OPTION value?

Here is the code for the modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modifyModal" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
 <form role="form" action="api/modifyAcct.php" method="get" id="modAcctForm" name="modAcctForm">
 <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" id="modpartnerName" name="modpartnerName" />
 <input readonly type="text" class="form-control" id="modpartnerCode" name="modpartnerCode" />
 <select class="form-control" id="modboiler" name="modboiler" />
   <option value=""></option> // <- #modboiler goes here
   <option value="Y">Yes</option>
   <option value="N">No<option>
 </select>
 <select class="form-control" id="modsurcharges" name="modsurcharges" />
   <option value=""></option> // <- #modsurcharges goes here
   <option value="Y">Yes</option>
   <option value="N">No</option>
 </select>
 <select class="form-control" id="modplatform" name="modplatform" />
   <option value=""></option> // <- #modplatform goes here
   <option value="Y"></option>
   <option value="N"></option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: var $option = $('#select-id option:first'); will get the option. What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery to select the first option and set the value.

```
$('#modplatform option:first').val($platform);
$('#modboiler option:first').val($boiler);
$('#modsurcharges option:first').val($surcharges);
```